# How to make text bold with if condition in Tkinter EntryBox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an app for laboratory calculation. I would like to add the option to make results bold if they are not in particular range. Suppose if the clear range is 130-230, but if in results the number are below 130 or above 230 they must become bold.

here is the code i am trying

```
    self.bold='\33[1m'
    self.s_cholestrol_entry=280
    self.s_cholestrol_low=130
    self.s_cholestrol_high=230
    self.s_cholestr = self.s_cholestrol_entry.get()
    if self.s_cholestrol_entry<self.s_cholestrol_low or  
                self.s_cholesterol_entry>self.s_cholesterol_high:
            self.bold+self.s_cholestrol_entry.insert(END,(self.s_cholestr))
    else:
            self.s_cholestrol_entry.insert(END,(self.s_cholestr))
```

btw i am using same code in python (without tkinter) and it work the way it should.

code without tkinter

```
    bold ='\33[1m'
    s_cholesterol_low="130"
    s_cholesterol_high="230"
    s_cholesterol_entry=(input("s_cholesterol_entry: "))
    if s_cholesterol_entry<s_cholesterol_low or s_cholesterol_entry>s_cholesterol_high:
            print(bold+s_cholesterol_entry)
    else:
            print(s_cholesterol_entry)
```

Comment: The entry widget doesn't use ansi escape sequences, and doesn't support different fonts or colors for part of the text.

Comment: @BryanOakley You're right - I'm incorrectly mixing it up with memories from a time a had to solve a similar issue with a `ScrolledText` widget! (Edit: erroneous comment deleted)